# How to add row on new datagridview where the data from other datagridview ? C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I wanna ask about winform datagridview on C# 
How I can add new row on my new datagridview from my old datagridview ?
Here's the example :

**My Old Table Column Header :**
Name **|** Price **|** Stock

Here's how i create my Old DataGridview

```
job = new MySqlCommand("select * from "+table, con);
DA = new MySqlDataAdapter(job);
DT = new DataTable();
DA.Fill(DT);
if(table == "barang")
{
     Dataview_Barang.DataSource = DT;
}
else if(table == "customer")
{
     Dataview_Customer.DataSource = DT;
}
```

**My New Table Column Header :**

Name **|** Price


So,how I can pass name and price value from old table when the new table cell programmatically?

Comment: Can you give a little more information?  How do your handle your data? Is it in a `List` , `DataTable` ...? do you populate your `DataGridView` by hand or by binding?

Comment: @MongZhu : I'm using DataGridViewRow to take value from my old datagridview but i have no idea to pass it to my new datagridview

Comment: I was talking about the old datagridview. How do you populate it. Can you post the code?

Comment: @MongZhu : i already fix my post , is that what you mean? @.@

Comment: Without any context for how/why/when you're passing data from one `DataGridView` to another, I'd suggest: **1)** Set the `NewDataGridView.DataSource` to the same `DataTable`. **2)** Handle `NewDataGridView.DataBindingComplete`. In that handler just set `NewDataGridView.Columns["Stock"].Visible` to false. - This way, both views reflect the same rows when new ones are added.

Comment: @OhBeWise : Thanks for the advice , i'll try your suggestion :D